# Acessing nested columns in pyspark dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark

I have an xml document that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Position>
    <Search>
        <Location>
            <Region>OH</Region>
            <Country>us</Country>
            <Longitude>-816071</Longitude>
            <Latitude>415051</Latitude>
        </Location>
    </Search>
</Position>
```

I read it into a dataframe:

```
df = sqlContext.read.format('com.databricks.spark.xml').options(rowTag='Position').load('1.xml')
```

I can see 1 column:

```
df.columns
['Search']

print df.select("Search")
DataFrame[Search: struct<Location:struct<Country:string,Latitude:bigint,Longitude:bigint,Region:string>>]
```

How do I access the nested columns. ex Location.Region?

Comment: Can you post a sample row of the dataframe that you get.

Comment: This was very helpful thankyou

Answer (score 14, accepted):

you can do something like below:

```
df.select("Search.Location.*").show()
```

output:

```
+-------+--------+---------+------+
|Country|Latitude|Longitude|Region|
+-------+--------+---------+------+
|     us|  415051|  -816071|    OH|
+-------+--------+---------+------+
```